# Pre-populate Sqlite database for use in application

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to create a quiz-like application where I use an Sqlite database to store the questions.
I then have to pre-populate the database and thinking of use Sql Asset helper (https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to ship the application with the database.

Is this a good solution?

What is the easiest way of populating the database? (There will be 500+ records in the db-table)

Comment: Structured Query Language.

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://gist.github.com/donaldlittlepie/1271795

Copy the pre-populated db to assets folder.

Comment: Thank you, but what is the easiest way to actual produce the database file (asset.db)?
I'm not looking forward to use the shell to produce the tables and them extract them from the emulator... Are there any good programs just to create the file?